# How to increase values in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I want to increase the current number in the database.

Example: If the number in the database is 0 I want it to increase by 1 every time I use the PostImage command.

The Error: When I console.log(debug) It gives undefined

```
const attachment = await interaction.options.getAttachment("input");
            const caption = await interaction.options.getString("caption");
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get("988214204660064286");

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor({ name: `${username} Posted`, iconURL: `${profilePicData}` })
                .setColor("#303236")
                .setDescription(`${caption}`)
                .setImage(`${attachment.url}`)
                .setFooter({ text: `user ID: ${userId}`, iconURL: `${profilePicData}` })
            channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then(async (msg) => {
                await msg.react("");
                await msg.react("");
            });

            db.findOneAndUpdate({
                UserId: userId,
                PostAmount: 1
            })
            const dubug = data.map((x) => `${x.PostAmount}`).join('\n');
            console.log(dubug)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing a data on `mongoose` uses `{$inc: {your_data}}`

```
db.findOneAndUpdate({
    UserId: userId,
    PostAmount: 1 //You can now remove these one.
}, {$inc: {PostAmount: +1}}, async(err, data) => {
   if(data) {
      data.PostAmount += 1;
      await data.save();
   }
})
```

> You should remove these code line **PostAmount: 1** because `UserId` Will find its own data on database.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the value of `PostAmount` by 1, you can simply get the document, change the value of `PostAmount` to `PostAmount + 1` and save the document

```js
let doc = await db.findOne({ UserId: userId });
doc.PostAmount = doc.PostAmount + 1;
await doc.save();
```

Besides that, `debug` returns undefined because it is not defined. It is probably because in the debug definition it tries to map `data` which I don't see defined either.

Comment: its not adding the value its setting to the number thats in the db here log: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62b144c88e8b7500d603c957"),
  UserId: '809213892857167942',
  Username: 'Abel',
  PostAmount: '0111',
  __v: 0
}